# What neck damage might be caused by general usage of flappies?

Tags: orthopedics, posture, neck, footwear, barefoot

<sub>**Preface 1:** This question is about **flappies** → flipflops/sandals/clogs and other similar footwear that is flat and that probably was made of a foamy-plastic liquid that have become solidified but whatever the material is, is too flat and maladjusted to human feet anyway.</sub>

<sub>**Preface 2:** I don't ask this question about a personal problem I currently suffer from → in the past, while using flappies generally daily, I did generally daily suffered from a mild right neck pain that was irradiated to the right shoulder and accompanied with popping joints from their area (especially from the shoulder), but after I stopped using flappies generally, 99% of the time, and started to go anywhere with new shoes or barefotted instead, than, humbly, that problem was gone - I no longer suffer from it.</sub>

---

While flappies does give some protection from walking hazards, I get the impression they can cause various bodily damages, including neck damage.
From searching accessible information on this footwear and plausible effects I found inconsistency in the naming of the footwear itself and little accessible data on possible problems; in between I found these:

- **Bad posture or support:**<sup>[1](https://newsnetwork.mayoclinic.org/discussion/mayo-clinic-minute-best-shoes-for-healthy-feet/)</sup> Flappies' surface is usually maladjusted all foot arch types (normal and not) resulting in foot pain, leg pain, lower back pain and increase of pressure on spines in general
- **Bad Shock Absorbance**<sup>[2](http://www.somasense.co.za/blog/how-flip-flops-affect-muscles-posture-gait)</sup> likely resulting in [heel sprain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprain), knee pain and lower back pain
- **Plantar fascia** development, due to either of the above
- **Tendon pressure**<sup>[3](https://www.forbes.com/2006/05/03/flipflop-foot-problems_cx_sy_0504htow.html)</sup> that might result in tendonitis.
- It can be very hard, if sometimes at all possible to use adjusted [shoe inserts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_insert) with flappies, which naturally raises the chance for problems by proper positioning and fixing (splinting) of the shoe insert to the flappy.

**What neck damage might be caused by general usage of flappies?**

Comment: I asked https://flippies.shoes/contact-us/ this question, and they said that they were unaware of any potential issues.

Comment: I up voted your comment.